# Error using matlab.io.fits.openFile - cannot open FITS files

Tags: matlab

I am running a code that uses the [`fitsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fitsread.html) function to open my fits movies and analyse them. It was working perfectly fine until about a week ago, when, without me doing anything, it started giving the following error whenever I try to run it:

```
Error using matlab.io.fits.openFile (line 48)

Unable to open file. File might be corrupt or filename might have unsupported
characters.

Error in fitsread>read_image_hdu (line 412)

fptr = fits.openFile(info.Filename);

Error in fitsread (line 125)
        data = read_image_hdu(info,1,raw,pixelRegion);
```

I have tried manually checking the properties of such files using the `fitsinfo` function and nothing was wrong with the files themselves. I have also tried to re-set the default MATLAB path, delete them from the working folder and re-download them from a central University server where they were originally stored upon acquisition on a microscope, but it didn't help either. A collaborator has tried running the same code on his machine and it works well. I get this same error on both MATLAB versions R2011b and R2015b. It originally used to work on R2011b with the same files.

Thanks in advance to whoever will be able to help!